# How do I display my icon on the far left of the box component in ReactJs

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

I want to display my globe Icon to the far right end of the box (as i have marked in red)
I have tried everything but it dosen't move.. If i change the position to absolute it gives me double globe icon somehow .I have also tried align contents , margin and padding but nothing works. If any one knows how to change that please help.

[The globe Icon](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mIAxH.png)

```js
const Navbar = () => {
    const [flagDropdownIsVisible, setFlagVisibility] = useState(false);
    return (
        <>
                <NavbarContainer>
                    <NavLogo to= '/'>
                        <img src={logo} alt='logo' width="150" height="30" />
                        </NavLogo>
                        
                    <LanguageButtonWrapper>
                    <RoundButton onClick={() => setFlagVisibility(true)}>
                        <img src= {globe} alt="" />
                    </RoundButton>
                 
                    <LanguageDropdown

                        isVisible={flagDropdownIsVisible}
                        setIsVisible={setFlagVisibility}
                        position={{ left: 0 }}
                    />
                </LanguageButtonWrapper> 

                                    
                </NavbarContainer>
        </>
    )
}

export default withTranslation() (Navbar);
```

```js
import styled from 'styled-components';
import { Link as LinkR } from 'react-router-dom'


export const NavbarContainer = styled.div `
    display: flex;
    justify-content: space-between;
    height: 500px;
    z-index: 1;
    width: 80%;
    padding-top: 20px;    
    max-width: 1100px;
`;

export const NavLogo = styled(LinkR)
`
    left:0;
    padding-top: 10px;
    padding-left:25px;
    
    
`;


export const Icon = styled.div `
    display:block;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    right: 0;
    transform: translate(-100%, 60%);
    font-size: 1.8rem;
    cursor: pointer;
`;


export const RoundButton = styled.button `
-moz-box-align: center;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
border-radius: 20px;
padding: 0px;
height: 40px;
width: 40px;
border: 1px solid rgb(38, 36, 57);
background-color: rgb(28, 26, 40);
position: relative;
  
cursor: pointer;
display: flex;

`;

export const LanguageButtonWrapper = styled.div `
    position:relative;    
`;
```

[This is whAT HAPPENS AFTER i perform the changes](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sJUNw.png)

Comment: you've defined the Icon component but havent used it anywhere in the code. Also, how much do you know about absolute/relative positioning in css? I think it'd be beneficial to read about it. It's hard to test exactly what you're trying to do because we can't run the code you wrote, but basically you define the parent (element whose corner you child should be in) as relative and the child as absolute and then play with the top/bottom/left/right values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
<NavbarContainer>
  <NavLogo to='/'>
    <img src={logo} alt='logo' width='150' height='30' />
  </NavLogo>
  <LanguageButtonWrapper>
    <LanguageDropdown
      isVisible={flagDropdownIsVisible}
      setIsVisible={setFlagVisibility}
      position={{ left: 0 }}
    />
  </LanguageButtonWrapper>
  <Filler />
  <RoundButton onClick={() => setFlagVisibility(true)}>
    <img src={globe} alt='' />
  </RoundButton>
</NavbarContainer>
```

and Filler is this:

```
const Filler = styled.div`
  flex: 1;
`
```

also change the `NavbarContainer` width to `100%` or `100vw`

Comment: The icon shifts to the corner like I wanted ...But on clicking the Icon i Get double Globe Icon . I have added that image to my Question.